# PHP script seems to return null using PDO on SQL statement with aggregate but works in MySQL workbench

Tags: php, mysql

I have been using this PHP script with PDO for other pages and works fine so I suspect there is something wrong with my SQL but copying it into MySQL workbench returns me three rows as I expect like so:

> voteCount, mphoto
>   '3', '170066'
>   '1', '168304'
>   '1', '169126'

I am just learning to use aggregate functions (COUNT in particular) so I am suspicious of that being my problem but am clueless to what is going wrong.  I am also not seeing an echo of any PDO error that should be caught so I think it is not that.  Here is my code:

```
$winnerstmt = queryWinner('mphoto');
echo "here is our var dump:".var_dump($winnerstmt);

function queryWinner($category)
{
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT($category) AS voteCount,$category 
            FROM studentVote WHERE $category!=111111 
            GROUP BY $category ORDER BY voteCount DESC LIMIT 3;";
    // TODO following echo is for debug
    echo $sql;
    databaseQuery($sql); 
}

function databaseQuery($sql)
{
    $hostname="hidden from post";
    $dbname = "hidden from post";
    $username = "hidden from post";
    $passwd = "hidden from post";
    $row = '';
    try {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8",
                  $username,
                $passwd);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); 

        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        echo "We made it past the db query without an error";
        return $stmt; 

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "we Received a Database error";
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return $e;
    }
}
```

The output I am getting is this:
SELECT COUNT(mphoto) AS voteCount,mphoto FROM studentVote WHERE mphoto!=111111 GROUP BY mphoto ORDER BY voteCount DESC LIMIT 3;
We made it past the db query without an error
null

Comment: Your queryWinner function doesnt return anything. Always run your PHP with `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to see this kind of silly errors.

Comment: Facepalm....  thank you. Never knew about error_reporting function as I would have assumed that was the default....

Comment: Wait, I was wrong. error reporting won't help here. May be a good IDE, like PHPStorm would highlight the issue.